# Internal Testing Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

We are trying to set up internal test track in Google Play Console for a new never published before app. I created a release and added testers....

- I was expecting testers to be notified, maybe via email but nothing yet. Is there an automated way to let the testers know?
- When I send the link to testers, the link opens screenshot page, but "download it on Google Play" link either shows "item not found" or it keeps loading forever

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have you got this solved? I'm experiencing the same "downloading forever" behavior.

Comment: @FreeBud If you are submitting for the fist time. the must be an initial review before any testing. Only after that inital review will the app be available for testing.

Comment: Thanks. I did get a successful "Pre-launch report" by email... is that it?

Comment: Internal apps are now available [without passing an initial review first](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en-GB&rd=1#start&closed_open_beta&multiply_test&closed_beta&open_beta&closed_groups&games&version_codes&track_status&when_internal_test&internal_test&create_additional_track). When publishing for the first time it will have a temporary name and store listing for up to 48 hours.